# Android app run other app and return to main app

Tags: android

I have defined following action in MainActivity class after click some button.

```
mSynchronizeData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){
            String packageName = "com.veryfit2hr.second";
            Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
            ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
            startActivity(intent);
            SystemClock.sleep(15000);
        }
    }
});
```

When other app is opening I want to return to the previos application after defined 15 seconds delay? I tried with  `MainActivity.super.onBackPressed();`
I didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: There is a startActivityForResult() API that you can look into. If the other app is able to notify its completion, then once finished, control will come back to your app.

Comment: @kdas I have to manually come back from this second app.

Comment: If you are launching an activity of the 2nd app, then thats the UI piece of an application. After you've launched the intent, when the 2nd app's activity is drawn on the screen, your app would automatically go in background. To bring your own app in the foreground, try this. 
1. Launch intent for 2nd app.
2. Start a timer or background thread or service etc (which can run even when your own app is in paused state).
3. At the end of timer or bg thread wait, launch an intent of your own app activity

Comment: You can't force other app to close to return back to your app. Only thing you can do is start your own activity on top of other app.

Answer (score 1):

If you own the new activity you can simply call `finish()` after the desired time after it is created. However if you do not, one solution would be to start your own activity after 15 seconds, on top of the previously launched activity.

I would recommend against this pattern in general as it could be very confusing for the user to be launched between apps seemingly at random - but here is an implementation that could work.

Instead of locking up the main thread by calling `SystemClock.sleep(15000);`, you'll want to schedule the call to happen after 15 seconds. We can use [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler) for this.

```
Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
         Intent intent = // Create intent for your activity here
         startActivity(intent)
    }
}, 15000);
```

Comment: I think this is the opposite of what is requested, this will launch the activity after 15 seconds. It sounds like the desired effect is to have the activity launch immediately and then terminate after 15 seconds.

Comment: Yes, I should clarify - this is run after you've already launched the activity from the code in the original question. Since you cannot terminate an activity you do not own, launching your own activity on top is the next best thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the [finish()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish()) method on the new activity that is being launched, and time the 15s delay there.  From the docs:

> Call this when your activity is done and should be closed. The ActivityResult is propagated back to whoever launched you via onActivityResult().